# In a sentence such as 'she said I should say hello to the baby' - is 'to' functioning as a preposition?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, nominative-vs-oblique

In the following sentence, does the 'to' function as a preposition?

> She said I should say hello to the baby.

If it is a preposition, could it function as an oblique? Or is it just acting as an infinitive for 'the baby'?

Comment: Yes, it's the head of a prepositional phrase with a noun phrase object. _The baby_ is a noun phrase and only verbs can be infinitives.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence "She said I should introduce myself to the baby," the word "to" is not functioning as an infinitive marker, as there is no infinitive verb following it. Instead, it is functioning as a preposition, connecting the action of introducing oneself with the baby.

If you are speaking about "oblique grammatical relation", then "to the baby" can be considered an oblique.